# Stack around the variable 'folderPath' was corrupted

Tags: c++

Hi i'm using visual studio and trying to make a program that replicate itself to a disk, when i run it does just that, but then i get the message:

```
"*Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'folderPath' was corrupted*."
```

the code is as follows:

```
void copyToDrive(char driveLetter) {
    char folderPath[10] = { driveLetter };
    strcat(folderPath, ":\\");
    strcat(folderPath, FILE_NAME);
    char filename[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
    std::ifstream src(filename, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream dest(folderPath, std::ios::binary);
    dest << src.rdbuf();
    return;
}
```

what is causing it? and how can i fix that?

Comment: Will the string you put into `folderPath` ***never*** be longer than nine characters? That is, will `FILE_NAME` never be longer than six characters?

Comment: What *is* `FILE_NAME` by the way? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: #define FILE_NAME "app.exe" and folderPath is the address of the disk: will be something like d:\\app.exe

Comment: Your `folderPath` array is too small. `c:\app.exe` is 10 characters and you need one more for the nul terminator.

Comment: There's no need to edit the answer into the question, the question should only hold the question not the answer. If you have your own answer to your question add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `"app.exe"` is seven characters long. That means the total length of the string you construct will be ten characters long.

Unfortunately you seem to forget that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings, and that the *null-terminator* also needs space.

Since there is no space for the null-terminator (character `'\0'`) the last `strcat` call will write out of bounds of your `folderPath` array, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and the error you get).

The simple solution is to add one element to the array to make space for the terminator as well:

```
char folderPath[11];
```

A more correct solution is to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead, and not have to worry about the length.

And since you are working with paths I would suggest you use [`std::filesystem::path`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) (or [Boost filesystem `path`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) if you don't have C++17 available).